# iOS: Local Push Notification fire ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification) while app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios

is it possible to handle/process/execute something the moment local push notification is received even if the app is backgrounded?

What I've tried is this: in debug mode, create a local notification which fires 10 secs after the app starts, put a breakpoint inside public override void ReceivedLocalNotification (UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification), run the app, quickly push home button after start wait for 10 secs, local notification message arrived in the status bar but the breakpoint does not hit, starting the app via app drawer wont hit breakpoint either, tapping the notification message will hit breakpoint.

What I want is when the notification arrived, regardless of the app state (backgrounded or even terminated), the moment it comes to foreground do some task based on the notification received and regardless of the way how the user starts the app (via tapping the push message or via drawer).

I used local push notification in iOS as a alarm/timer, since iOS does not have AlarmManager like Android.

By the way I am using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: No, you will only get a call to `ReceivedLocalNotification` if your app is running in the foreground.  If your app is suspended then the notification is simply displayed.  If the user taps on the notification then the information is passed to your app.  If the user taps the app icon directly then no notification information is delivered to your app.  There is no method on IOS to force an app to execute at a particular time

Comment: If your app will only do one thing upon notification you can try adding a badge value, and add a method to check the badgevalue in viewDidAppear of every viewcontroller

Comment: Is that so... So is there any alternative to a timer of some sort or a technique that does something like this? all I need is to check if a set timer when the app is running is over, after app is terminated and reopened via app drawer, taking into account that the user might change the device time to cheat/bypass the alarm (if using the current time and end time offset obvious approach)

Comment: The only reliable "cheat proof" way to check for elapsed time is to ask a server on the Internet.